# Changing app settings using portal.azure not working post creation

Tags: azure, azureportal

I am using portal.azure.com to create an application, initially when the application is created I do get a settings page where I am able to edit a lot of things like multitenancy, add permissions create secrets. After logging out or changing them and moving focus away from those elements I am not able to locate a way to edit. It used to work for me before but hasn't today! maybe it's just a pebkac? any inputs will be appreciated.

Based on the comments here is what I am trying to do:

- Locate Enterprise application in Azure portal and create an application

[image: Locate Enterprise application in Azure portal and create an application]

[image: After clicking here it takes me to the enterprise App]

[image: This actually creates the application]

- Once the application is created as shown below the settings option we see are only available initially, also the permissions eventhough set correctly are not visible post creation.

[image: The settings option that you see here is not available once you have done changes and try to do them again]

Comment: Take a look at CloudConfigurationManager, which might be the answer here. It will read configuration file regardless of the environment we are in

Comment: Thanks, so I am not missing something obvious in the azure portal?

Comment: Could you provide more details on the "application" since there are quite a few offerings in Azure? Perhaps, add a screenshot. If you're talking about Service Principal accounts (App Registration in the Azure Portal) keys, you won't be able to edit them once you leave that blade, you will need to create a new one.

Comment: added more details